# Запуск php и получение данных

Tags: php, javascript, userjs

Пишу пользовательский java скрипт для хрома. Получается так что мне нужно что бы при заходе на определенный сайт. Скрипт запустил php, который в свою очередь получает данные с сервера в виде массива.
В итоге имею `javascript.js`, который запускается на нужной странице и отдельно файл `server.php`, которые, если отдельно запустить его получит массив `$array`.
Проблема вся в том как теперь через `javascript.js` запустить `server.php` и получить в скрипт массив `$array`.

Поправил позже!

Суть в том, что php файл делает `get` запрос на сервер и парсит xml, который преобразуется в нужный для меня массив. Я просто не знаю можно сделать подобное средствами js. сам код server.php.

```
$fp = fsockopen("example.ru", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$fp) {
            return;
        }else {
            $pknum = 1470;
            $data = urlencode($pknum);

            $out = "GET /compnum/api/api/GetPassport?CompNum=$data HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            $out .= "Host: example.ru\r\n";
            $out .= "Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            $out .= "Content-length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
            $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            $out .= $data."\r\n\r\n";

            $xml = '';

            fwrite($fp, $out);
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $xml = fgets($fp);
            }
            fclose($fp);

            $sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $arr2d2=array();
            foreach ($sxml->Component as $arr) {
            $q=(string)$arr->TypeName;

    $arr2d2[$q][] = htmlspecialchars((string)$arr->Condition);

            }
```

Может кто-нибудь помочь с переделкой данного пхп под ajax для javascript.

Comment: `ajax` наше всё

Comment: А сервер, на который Вы кладёте свой файл *.php, предусмотрен? А то Вы его как-то забыли упомянуть... Без него никак. А так - лучше всего научить server.php отдавать JSON, вызывать его через AJAX и потом уже этот JSON разбирать в Вашем скрипте.

Comment: Изменил главное сообщение.

Comment: Вот именно в JS вам и надо переписать данный код. потому как php на клиенте работать не будет, она должна быть на сервере и к нему должно идти обращение. Как уже вам говорили выше - ключевое слово `ajax` - это как раз метод обращения из js скрипта непосредственно на web-сервера с запросами

Comment: Хорошо спасибо буду пытаться.

Comment: Может кто-нибудь помочь с переделкой данного пхп под ajax для javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам на выход нужен **JSON**, то можете по началу получить **XML** и с помощью следующих методов получить желаемый респонс:

**PHP**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$json_data = json_decode(json_encode($xml), 1);

echo $json_data;
```

**JS**

```
$.post('/url/, function(response){
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    // Тут уже делаете то, что Вам надо с JSON массивом
});
```

Всё проще, чем кажется